# I need to read a file using linux commands and remove the text form "@" in domain name

Tags: r, linux

I need to read a file using linux commands and remove the text form "@" in domain name .

For example if a text file as

Input:
abc@gmail.com

Output:
abc

Comment: Maybe `sub("@.*", "", "abc@gmail.com")`

Answer (score -1):

This Linux command reads a file, and prints the modified content on the screen:
`sed -r "s/@.*//" your_file`

If you want to edit the file in place, overwriting the original file, you can use `sed -r -i "s/@.*//" your_file`